# Why do I have an error for adding a variable to an ArrayList?

Tags: java, arraylist

I have a class like the follows:

```
public class Author
{

   public ArrayList<String> quotes;
   private String name;

   public Author(String name)
   {
      this.name = name;

   }
}
```

Now I want to add stuff to the arraylist called quotes, in another class:

```
public class Page 
{

    Author John = new Author("John Smith");

    John.quotes.add("asdf"); //but this is wrong. The add() isn't recognized

    ...
}
```

As you can see, I can't add variables to the ArrayList quotes from another class. How can I do this?

Comment: you have to define ArrayList as a static or define a method in the class ' Author ' which can add the elements in the arraylist

Comment: @ManthanB `quotes` is `public`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you have **not instantiate** `ArrayList<String>` then you must get `NullPointerException`,

but if you instantiate it like below attached picture, you will definitely get success.

Refer this output,

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Because you didn't instantiate `quotes`. You could do something like

```
public Author(String name)
{
    this.name = name;
    this.quotes = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

Comment: Thanks but I just realiezd that wasn't the issue. I am using Android Studio and it doesn't matter which class, using add() simply says "Cannot resolve symbol 'add' ". I resolved it by adding the quote.add(); inside a class. It's strange, seems ilke an Android Studio problem. Thanks for the help anyways.

Answer (score 0):

You are not creating a object of `public ArrayList<String> quotes;` It will refer to null when

> Author John = new Author("John Smith"); //When run this code.

quotes will refer to `null` actually. This is the reason behind the `Exception` is Raised.

Hope You Under stand.

```
public class Author
{

   public ArrayList<String> quotes;
   private String name;
   public Author(){
     this.quotes = new ArrayList<String>();
    }
   public Author(String name)
   {
      this();
      this.name = name;

   }
}
```

try this definition for `Class Author` . Resolve your `exception`